# making a variable a class in javascript

Tags: javascript

In my application, I have some tags that look like this

`x Beer`   `x Wine` `x Gummy Bears`

If you click on the 'x' it's supposed to delete the tag.

The tags are created as you see below, with a link around the 'x'.  The code inside the <%= %> is ruby. The parameterize method will, for example, make the Gummy Bears tag like 'Gummy-bears'.

```
<a href="#" class="link tag" data-span="<%= tag.name.parameterize %>"data-question="<%= @question.id %>" data-tag="<%= tag.name%>" >x</a>

<span class="<%=  tag.name.parameterize %>"><%= tag.name %></span>
```

I have JavaScript click events set up on the 'x' link. I am able to remove the 'x' immediately upon the click, but I can't get the actual tag name removed until a page refresh, which is not what I want. In order to get the tag.name removed immediately, I created a span class around the tag name that's the same as one of the html data attributes on the 'x' link. I saved the data attribute to a variable (this.span)

```
   this.spanVariable = $(r.target).attr("data-span");  #gets the tag.name parameterize from the data-span
```

For example, if it was the Gummy Bear tag that was clicked, this.spanVariable would now be 'Gummy-Bear'.

and then I would like to empty the html of the class 'Gummy-Bear', so I want to do something like this to evaluate the javascript variable so it becomes the class. I thought I could evaluate javascript inside of #{} but I guess not :(

```
   $('.#{this.spanVariable}').html('');
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, basically make the variable evaluate so it can become the class that's also a jquery object (i.e. i can call jquery methods on).

Comment: You could simply use a checkbox and a label for less headaches and style if necessary.

Comment: what about jQuery.next()?

Comment: You could put them together (they do belong together): http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/qPuRH/

Comment: @elclanrs would you mind showing how to do it with checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.' + this.spanVariable).remove();
```

This way should avoid race conditions, call some ajax, and do stuff when it returns:

```
$('.xclass').click(function(e) {
  var spanVariable = $(this).data("span");
  $.ajax("/my/server/endpoint?tag=" + spanVariable, {
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
      $('.' + result.spanVariable).remove();
      $('.tag[data-span=' + result.spanVariable + ']').remove();
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('Couldn't remove the tag...');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This works, however, with the other solutions available, I don't think this way is the best way (totally my fault), because if a user tries to click on multiple tags in a short period of time, I'm wondering if spanVariable might change rapidly before server side code responds etc.

Comment: This is all client-side... Also, if your worried about that, use a local variable instead of object...

Comment: If you're using the object to update stuff on the server side, maybe you should consider tracking the tags with an array, instead. That way the server doesn't need to try to keep up with the client.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In one method (the method you see in the OP), I get the data from the click event,and then call a method that does the ajax request to remove the tag server side. On the successful response, another method is called which removes the tag from the client (i.e. once I know it's been removed server side).  How might I track position in the array doing it that way?

Comment: I'm not sure how you've implemented the call to the server, but I'm updating my answer with something that might work...

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm using Backbone. After the click event is handled in the view, it calls a method on the Backbone model, which makes the ajax request. That's significant because the success response is in the Backbone model (not the view), and I can't access that dom from that model (views in backbone are connected to the dom), but I can trigger a response in the model that the View listens to, so I need to pass something back in the response from the model to the view to tell the view to remove that tag.The solution you posted, if used in backbone,  assumes everything happens in the View.

Comment: Never used backbone, but maybe you could tell something in your view to listen for the tag removal event (or whatever you listen for) and fire a function similar to the one I posted...

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps mixing server and client side? 
Try

```
$('.'+this.spanVariable).empty();
```

Comment: You're right. I confused server and client side. This works, however, with the other solutions available, I don't think this way is the best way (totally my fault), because if a user tries to click on multiple tags in a short period of time, I'm wondering if spanVariable might change rapidly before server side code responds etc, and then desired effect won't be achieved.